# In subprocess.Popen, what's the difference between passing stdin=None and stdin=sys.stdin?

Tags: python

What would be difference between the below two commands? And would it vary by platform (e.g. Windows or Linux)?

Note: I believe this question applies equally for each of the keyword arguments `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.

A:

```
subprocess.Popen(some_command, stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
```

B:

```
subprocess.Popen(some_command)
```

(Assuming we have `subprocess` and `sys` imported.)

The docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html say:

> With the default settings of `None`, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.

Based on that, for `stdin`, it sounds like `sys.stdin` would give the child process the same file handle as the parent, which sounds the same as what the docs describe for `None`.

Comment: I agree, they're equivalent. Why would there be a difference? Using `None` is a convenience, since you don't have to import `sys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.stdin` isn't *precisely* the standard input of the current Python process, as you can assign a new file handle to it. Its value is *initialized* with the process's standard input, though. Child processes will inherit the original standard input, preserved in `sys.__stdin__`. An example:

```
import sys
import subprocess

with open("foo.txt") as f:
    sys.stdin = f
    subprocess.call(["cat"])
```

If you run this with an appropriate set of files:

```
$ echo hi > foo.txt
$ echo bye > bar.txt
$ python tmp.py < bar.txt
bye
```

then the output will be `bye`, not `hi`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. So then, using `sys.__stdin__` would be equivalent to `None`? (Or `sys.__stdout__` for `stdout`, etc.) 

Is there a common reason to reassign `sys.std{in,out,err}`? Perhaps for mocking in unit tests? Based on your answer then, it seems that passing `stdin=sys.stdin` would be necessary to make these calls to `Popen` testable.

Comment: For tests, you usually provide some static file-like object (like `stdin=io.StringIO(...)`) or you open a known file. `sys.stdin` is used, for example, by `input()`, but `sys.__stdin__` is what any child process will inherit.